# asp.net dynamic sitemap with querystring? Session variable seems like overkill

Tags: asp.net, webforms, query-string, sitemap

I'm using ASP.NET WebForms.
I'm using the standard sitemap provider.

*Home > User > Account > Entry*

Going to the home page should have a user selection screen.
Clicking on a user should list out the user's accounts with options to edit, delete, add accounts.

Selecting an account should list out all the user's account's entries with options to edit delete and add entries.

How do you normally pass this information between pages?

I could use the query string, but then, the sitemap doesn't work. The sitemap only has the exact page without the query string and therefore loses the information.

*/User/Account/List.aspx?User=123*

*/User/Account/Entry/List.aspx?User=123&Account=322*

I could use a session variable, but this seems overkill.

Thoughts and suggestions very appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you've discovered the default ASP.NET sitemap provider does not work with querystring parameters very well.  However, you can create a custom sitemap provider that can handle querystring parameters however you want - [Adding QueryString Parameters to the SiteMapNode](http://weblogs.asp.net/jgaylord/archive/2008/06/04/adding-querystring-parameters-to-the-sitemapnode.aspx).

Comment: Is using the query string the best way to do this?
Should I use some other form of data storage to track where the user is?

Comment: I think the querystring is the best way - remember it is a web application, and passing identifiers through the querystring is how almost all dynamic http applications work.